# Should we reopen the "cold temperature on exam performance" question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

A question titled [Effect of cold temperatures on exam performance](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/206388) was recently closed. The question is decoupled from the "inciting incident" and simply asks if there is any scholarship on the effects of room temperature on exam performance.

To me this question should be left open. True, this could be considered a question about the "content of physiology," but the fact that it strongly relates to best practices for exams makes it firmly on-topic here, in my view. If the question had simply been "What should I do if I show up to give an exam and the room is extremely cold?", I doubt anyone would have voted to close. The fact that this question specifically asked for evidence rather than just "common sense solutions" makes it a stronger, not weaker, question in my view.

What do you think?

**Update:** Question is now reopened.

Comment: By now, I do agree. It's really little different from "what are the effects of X on academic issue Y, and is there research on it?", and that does seem to be in the spirit of Academia.SE. Maybe make this meta question a little more general?

Comment: I agree as well, and have voted to reopen.

Comment: Think of the inverse: A prof wondering "the room I used was really cold, should I adjust scores?" (the answer would be yes, apparently) would be on-topic.

Comment: Seems on-topic to me... Flirts with being opinion-based, but it's a real judgment call that instructors may have to make, with real consequences.

Comment: fine with me, I voted to reopen.

Comment: The question is now reopened.